# @Qualifierの使い方

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

JavaのSpring Frameworkをつかって、webアプリケーションを作成しています。
しかし、複数のBeanを登録したいのですが、うまくいきません。

#### 目標

複数のBeanを扱いたい

#### エラーメッセージ

```
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

#### 自分でエラー解消のために実施したこと

@Qualifierの付与

#### ソースコード

User.java

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("User")
public class User implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    private int userId;
    private int pass;
    
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    
    public int getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(int pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

}
```

Info.java

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("Info")
public class Info implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private int examId;
    private String examName;
    private String examDate;
    
    public int getExamId() {
        return examId;
    }


    public void setExamId(int examId) {
        this.examId = examId;
    }


    public void setExamName(String examName) {
        this.examName = examName;
    }

    public void setExamDate(String examDate) {
        this.examDate = examDate;
    }

    public String getExamName() {
        return examName;
    }

    public String getExamDate() {
        return examDate;
    }

}
```

ServiceUserImpl.java

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.demo.entity.Info;
import com.example.demo.entity.User;

@Service
public class ServiceUserImpl implements TestService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDao dao;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("User")
    User user;
    

    @Override
    public List selectWhere(Object t) {
        
        User u = (User)t;
        
        List<User> list = dao.selectWhere(u);
        
        return list;
        
    
    }
}
```

ServiceExamInfoImpl.java

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dao.ExamInfoDao;
import com.example.demo.entity.Info;

@Service
public class ServiceExamInfoImpl implements TestService {
    
    @Autowired
    ExamInfoDao dao;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Info")
    Info info;
    
    

    @Override
    public List selectWhere(Object t) {
        
        Info info = (Info)t;
        
        List<Info> list = dao.selectWhere(info);
        
        return list;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

質問文中のエラーメッセージが、どの bean に対して出ているのかが重要です。質問文中のエラーメッセージが出力された直前に、何が問題になっているのかもまた出力されていると思いますので確認してみてください。

質問文中のコードで可能性があるとすると `TestService` を auto-wire しようとした場合が考えられますが、この場合ですと、例えば次のように `@Qualifier` を付与すれば解消するでしょう。

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("serviceUserImpl")
    private TestService testService;
...
```

補足:

デフォルトの qualifier 値は bean name であり、また、デフォルトの bean name はクラス名の最初を小文字にしたものです。
つまり、何も明示しなかった場合 `ServiceUserImpl` の qualifier 値は `serviceUserImpl` になります。

[1.9.4. Fine-tuning Annotation-based Autowiring with Qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.19/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value.

[1.10.6. Naming Autodetected Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.19/reference/html/core.html#beans-scanning-name-generator)

> If such an annotation contains no name `value` or for any other detected component (such as those discovered by custom filters), the default bean name generator returns the uncapitalized non-qualified class name.